# Where is the .NET downloads cache?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Reading the .NET guides on Shadow copying, specifically the property [CachePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomainsetup.cachepath?view=netframework-4.8):

> In order for this property to have an effect, the ApplicationName property must also be set. If the ApplicationName property is not set, the CachePath property is ignored and the shadow copy cache location defaults to the download cache.

I can't find any information on this Downloads Cache. Where is it by default? Is it's path within the registry? How can I find it's path on a user's machine?

EDIT: I've found where the path is set in the registry, at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\DownloadCacheLocation`. However, on one of our customer's machine, the "Fusion" entry in the registry is missing. On their machine, the assemblies [are not shadow copied to the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225367/net-resolving-wrong-shadow-copy-path). Any ideas on where to dig to find out why?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What kind of problem do you currently have where locating that folder is part of the solution?

Comment: Messing with a mechanism like _Shadow Copying_ will bring you nothing but grief.  It works, and it's very deliberately hard to find.  Why do you want to find it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't want to mess with the Shadow Copy, it is messing with me. I maintain a VSTO add-in, which shadow copies assemblies by default. I use a third-party library to run a headless chromium browser. On startup, it resolves the chromium assembly and unpacks it. On a specific user's machine, the assembly is resolved to the shadow copy folder, however that folder DOES NOT EXIST on the user's machine. 

I have both a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225367/net-resolving-wrong-shadow-copy-path) about this and an open .NET ticket that haven't been answered in weeks.

Comment: @Flydog57 I don't want to mess with it, it's messing with me. We use a VSTO addin which uses ShadowCopy by default. ShadowCopy is broken on one of our users machine. The Assemblies do not get copied to the default path, but Assembly.Load().Location resolves the assembly in the default path. I want to know where the cache path is set so I can check the user's machine to see whats going on. See this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69225367/net-resolving-wrong-shadow-copy-path) I posted that has no replies

Comment: Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see where the process goes looking for assemblies. You may also see where it looks just before that to see where it looks to find it